# Constant and inconstant values using NI-DAQmx Python API although not issues with NI SignalExpress 2015

Tags: python, signal-processing, nidaqmx, daq-mx

**Introduction**

I encountered issues with extracting data using NI-DAQmx Python algorithms (using Python 3.11 on Anaconda, with Spyder as the IDE). The data remains unchanged when I alter the settings, yielding a constant, incorrect value. This question outlines my troubleshooting process and the steps taken to resolve the issue.

**Checking the Device Connected to the National Instruments (NI-DAQmx)**

***MAX***

Initially, I utilized MAX (Measurement and Automation Explorer) to verify the device's functionality. The device appeared to operate correctly, and test panel readings matched expected theoretical values :

[image: Figure 1]

***NI SignalExpress 2015***

Further testing with NI SignalExpress 2015 confirmed that the software could accurately retrieve the expected values, indicating no issues at this stage.

[image]

**Code Implementation in NI-DAQmx Python**

Despite anticipating seamless integration with the NI-DAQmx Python API, problems emerged: The values returned by basic algorithms were static and inconsistent with both expected fluctuations and previous measurements, displaying values such as 5.3, which were incongruent with prior results. Below, I detailed the algorithms attempted and their respective outcomes.

***First Algorithms and Results***

```
import nidaqmx
task = nidaqmx.Task()
task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai10")
task.start()
value = task.read()
print(round(value,1))
task.stop()
task.close()

$ python script_1.py
5.4
```

***Second Algorithms and Results***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
import nidaqmx
from nidaqmx.constants import AcquisitionType
import pdb 

# Configuration de l'appareil NI-DAQmx pour deux canaux
device_name = "Dev1"  # Le nom de votre dispositif
sample_rate = 1000  # Taux d'échantillonnage en échantillons par seconde
samples_per_read = 1  # Nombre d'échantillons à lire à chaque itération

# Initialisation des données de graphique
xdata, ydata1, ydata2 = [], [], []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1, = plt.plot([], [], '-', label='Canal ai9')
line2, = plt.plot([], [], '-', label='Canal ai10')
plt.title('Données NI-DAQmx en temps réel')
plt.xlabel('Échantillons')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.legend()

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(1, 6.5)  # Ajustez les limites pour refléter la nouvelle plage de tension
    return line1, line2



def update(frame):
    with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
        # Ajoutez ici les deux canaux à la tâche
        for ch in channels:
            task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan(f"{device_name}/{ch}")
        task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(rate=sample_rate, sample_mode=AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS, samps_per_chan=samples_per_read)
        data = task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=samples_per_read)
    xdata.append(frame)
    # Mettez à jour les données pour les deux canaux
    ydata1.append(data[0])
    ydata2.append(data[1])
    line1.set_data(xdata, ydata1)
    line2.set_data(xdata, ydata2)
    if len(xdata) > 100:  # Défilement de l'axe x pour garder les 100 derniers points visibles
        ax.set_xlim(xdata[-100], xdata[-1] + 1)
    return line1, line2

# Animation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(0, 1000), init_func=init, blit=False, interval=50)

plt.show()
```

**Bug Resolution attempt**

I verified the device name and ports, ensuring accuracy in their specification. Additionally, I regularly cleared the device of any residual data to prevent issues related to data overflow or corruption.

**Conclusion**

I am at a loss regarding the cause of these discrepancies between NI SignalExpress 2015 and NI-DAQmx or how to rectify them. Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**ANSWER** (provided in the question until it is reopen to accept answers)

Here is the solution provided in github (https://github.com/ni/nidaqmx-python/issues/543#event-12171891209)

```
n MAX and SignalExpress, you are acquiring data with a +/-10 V range, but the Python add_ai_voltage_channel method sets `min_val=-5.0 `and `max_val=5.0` by default:

    def add_ai_voltage_chan(
            self, physical_channel, name_to_assign_to_channel="",
            terminal_config=TerminalConfiguration.DEFAULT, min_val=-5.0,
            max_val=5.0, units=VoltageUnits.VOLTS, custom_scale_name=""):
```

This is clipping your data to approximately a +/-5 V range. The reason it reads 5.3 V rather than 5 V is that X Series devices have a small amount of overrange so that software calibration doesn't reduce the usable range.

Try specifying `min_val=-10.0` and `max_val=10.0`.

And this is the following working script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
import nidaqmx
from nidaqmx.constants import (AcquisitionType, TerminalConfiguration)
import csv
import os
import time


# Ask the user for desired units
units = input("Enter the desired units (bar or mmHg): ").lower()

# Conversion function
def voltage_to_pressure(voltage, units):
    pressure_bar = (voltage / 10) * 1.6  # 0-10 V -> 0-1.6 bar
    if units == "bar":
        return pressure_bar  # Directly in bar
    elif units == "mmhg":
        return ( pressure_bar * 750.0616827 )-7  # 1 bar = 750.0616827 mmHg
    else:
        return None

# Configuration
device_name = "Dev1"
channel =  "ai10"
Tstop = 60 # Logging Time [seconds]
Ts = 2 # Sampling Time [seconds]
N = int(Tstop/Ts)
data = []
c_hg = 750.0616827

# CSV setup
csv_file_name = input("Enter the name for the CSV file (without extension): ") + ".csv"
csv_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", csv_file_name)

# Initialize CSV
with open(csv_file_path, mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Sample Number', 'ai10 (' + units + ')'])
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Correctly unpack the list returned by ax.plot to get the Line2D object for animation
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'r-', label='Channel ai10')  # Use comma to unpack

ax.set_xlim(0, 100)  # Set the x-axis limit

# Set y-axis based on units
if units == 'bar':
    ax.set_ylim(0.9, 1.11)  # For 'bar' units
else:
    ax.set_ylim(0.9*c_hg, 1.11*c_hg)  # For 'mmHg' units, using the conversion constant

ax.legend()
ax.set_title('NI-DAQmx Real-time Data')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel(f'Pressure ({units})')


xdata, ydata = [], []

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

def update(frame):
    with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
        task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan(f"{device_name}/{channel}", terminal_config=TerminalConfiguration.RSE, min_val=-10, max_val=10)
        voltage_reading = task.read()  # Ensure this returns a single reading directly
        pressure = voltage_to_pressure(voltage_reading, units)  # Convert directly
        ydata.append(pressure)
        xdata.append(frame * Ts)  # Assuming each frame represents a time step of Ts seconds
        line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
        if len(xdata) > 100:
            ax.set_xlim(xdata[-100], xdata[-1]+1)
        with open(csv_file_path, mode='a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([frame, pressure])
    return line,


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(1, 1000), init_func=init, blit=True, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of code

Comment: I provided a text form of the script and would like to post the answer @possum